# How use result of pnp response

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, typescript, pnp-js-core

I use PnP for getting SharePoint list item. But I don't really know, how use the result of my function.

I wish to get items of my SharePoint list using PnP and assign it to my list.

My code don't work:

```
  public render(): void {

    const element: React.ReactElement<IFaqProps > = React.createElement(
      Faq,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        items :  this.getFaqList()
        }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

    let ListFaq : IExampleItem[];
/*= [{Question:"question",Reponse:"response", Categorie :{Title : "SharePoint"} , Langue:"fr"},
{Question:"question",Reponse:"response", Categorie :{Title : "OnDrive"} , Langue:"fr"}];*/

this._getListData()
       .then((response) => {
         response.forEach((item: IExampleItem) => {
           alert(item.Question);
          return ListFaq.push(item);
         });
 });
return ListFaq;
}

   public _getListData(): Promise<IExampleItem[]> {
    return sp.web.lists.getByTitle("FAQ_List").items
    .select("Question", "Reponse","Categorie/Title", "Langue")
    .expand("Categorie")
    .get()
    .then((response) => {

       return response;
     });

    }
export interface IFaqProps {
  description: string;
  items: IExampleItem[];
}
export type IExampleItem = { Question: string; Reponse: string; Categorie: {Title :string}; Langue: string };
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code - set a breakpoint on `return response;` then check the result inside of response object. Add another then to your promise i.e.  `.then((items) => { console.log(items);})` then do whatever you want with the data in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the result in the state of the componment and put the request in `componentDidMount` method as it's a async request. You can take a reference of below code:

```
const response = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("FAQ_List").items
    .select("Question", "Reponse","Categorie/Title", "Langue")
    .expand("Categorie")
    .get();

const items: IExampleItem[] = response.map(item => {
        return {
          Title: item.Question,
          Size: item.Categorie,
          Name: item.Langue
        };


this.setState({ ...this.state, items });
```

For more details, you may take a reference of below sample:

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-async-await-sp-pnp-js/src/webparts/asyncAwaitPnPJs/components/AsyncAwaitPnPJs.tsx

BR